Error installing mySQLDB using pip Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
Unable to run django application in the latest amazon Linux AL2023 running python3.9
It reports mySQLDB module is not installed, I tried installing mysql module using pip and yum but nothing helped to solve the problem. The error we get is "Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually"
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/data/vpy38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/data/vpy38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient? 

When I tried installing it via pip Im getting the following error:
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/vpy38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/data/vpy38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/data/vpy38/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0ehmrzaq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0ehmrzaq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-0ehmrzaq/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 49, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 28, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output. 


OS: Amazon Linux2023
Python3.9
Please assist me resolving it.

Im having hard time with it, can anyone quickly help solve it.

To install mysqlclient on Linux, You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config # Debian / Ubuntu
% sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel pkgconfig # Red Hat / CentOS

Then you can install mysqlclient via pip now:
$ pip install mysqlclient

For customize build (POSIX):
mysqlclient uses pkg-config --cflags --ldflags mysqlclient by default for finding compiler/linker flags.
You can use MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS environment variables to customize compiler/linker options:
$ export MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS=`pkg-config mysqlclient --cflags`
$ export MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS=`pkg-config mysqlclient --libs`
$ pip install mysqlclient

See https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#description
